# Where is facsimileTelephoneNumber for User in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity has a facsimileTelephoneNumber. In migrating to Microsoft Graph we saw this property is no longer there - is this me not finding the new location, a temporary omission or even permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this property is not exposed (currently) by Microsoft Graph.  It is something that we can add, but we didn't because we weren't sure how many folks still use this - where individual users have fax numbers still.  Please feel free to vote for this feature on User Voice here:  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/18166054-microsoft-graph-api-user-fax-number.

Hope this helps,