# Are Azure AD Properties Assistant and facsimileTelephoneNumber exposed in the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Looking for confirmation that user properties: Assistant and facsimileTelephoneNumber

are or are not exposed in the Microsoft Graph API... Building a solution and need these properties pulled from users....

Anyone have a recommendation on how to extract these properties from all users in a tenant?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is facsimileTelephoneNumber for User in Microsoft Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231410/where-is-facsimiletelephonenumber-for-user-in-microsoft-graph)

Comment: Hey Marc, I saw that post. I wanted to see if the list of exposed properties has changed. I also do not see any information on if the assistant property is exposed by the graph api...