# Microsoft Graph API Business Fax

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using Microsoft Graph API to fetch the contacts information from Office 365 contacts. But we are not able to fetch Business Fax information in the json. We can enter business fax in the office 365 contact manually using Phone > Other > Business Fax option.

Can any one please help us on this.

Regards

Tarunjit Singh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is facsimileTelephoneNumber for User in Microsoft Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231410/where-is-facsimiletelephonenumber-for-user-in-microsoft-graph)